# Generics hell or what would it take to have assembly level type parameterization (assembly wide generics) in .NET

Tags: .net, generics, c#-4.0, programming-languages, language-features

Not sure what this question is exactly about.

Here is the problem. Suppose, I am working on a framework that is going to be packed into an assembly without source code available and shipped as a product. From the very beginning the framework is developed with extensibility in mind, by which I mean that some target domain details/data/classes are to be defined by the end user / assembly that refers the framework. One of the ways to enable it is to use generics in the framework for everything to be defined later. But once a generic is introduced to a single class all dependent/referring classes and methods have to re-declare it with all the exact constraints. It's not a big deal to pass around a single generic, but things go very quickly out of control when you have to deal, say with 8 of them, which is not something uncommon at all. In every little class in your framework you have to put several lines of just redeclared type parameters that are all the same among all of your classes. It seems like a quick and dirty solution would be just to have some kind of c++like macro that would add the same generic declaration to all (most of) classes. But C# doesn't have macros, so you have to do it by hands. Here is where we come to a question: what would it take to get these parameters out of brackets and declare them once at the assembly (project) level? So that you don't have to write "public class Entity**< TField>** { ... }", because TField is defined and whenever you see it, it means the class knows about it implicitly using the same declaration as the one at the assembly level. By linking such generic assemblies a developer has to provide all type arguments before they are able to use it, or if some parameters are still unbound, to redeclare them for later use.

Questions:

- have you ever found yourself in a situation like this?
- do you think that having this feature might be helpful?
- if so, how do you currently get along without one?
- for those who is working on c#: what is a chance that you guys will add this to some new version of c#?

Thank you!

**UPDATE:**

I didn't want to go too much into details, but did it as you wished.
It's hard to make up a good illustrative example, so let me just share the existing situation. I am working on a text processing framework where I have a core lib that tokenizes the text and has all possible patterns to match it. What it doesn't know anything about is how to deal with parts of speech like nouns and verbs. Luckily there is another assembly that can do that. Now the goal is to extend the patterns from the core library with knowledge of parts of speech from another library. The way I did it is I added a special pattern to the core lib named "CustomPattern" that is parameterized by an arbitrary class which can be replaced with anything. In our case it is PartOfSpeach enum. Take a look at the code passage at https://gist.github.com/2651642.

Question here, how to avoid having the TDetails generic in the core lib and yet be able to use a custom pattern with arbitrary data attached to it?

The only requirement here is that **we have to keep the code strictly typed as it is right now**.

Comment: "One of the ways to enable it is to use generics .." - You probably completly misunderstood what generics were meant to.

Comment: @Euphoric Explain why generics are not appropritate, if you think so.

Comment: @ewernli - Read the reposnes. Interfaces are much more apropriate for extension and dependency inversion than generics. Most of the time, you don't need exact type, only the specific contract.

Comment: I see no problem with example you showed. And it is kind of missing the "you have to deal, say with 8 of them" you say in your question. Which I believe is core problem.

Comment: Just a comment of your code: Replace whole NextPattern with IEnumerable. The function is same and you wont need to deal with your own linked list. And Matcher and Visitor seem kind of redundant to me, so I would merge them.

Comment: I tried to mess a little with your code. http://pastebin.com/YWUrzuZz I removed unnecessary things and changed the generics and interfaces a little.

Answer (score 4):

> have you ever found yourself in a situation like this?

Yes.

> do you think that having this feature might be helpful?

I think being able to define/share generic constraints across classes would be useful, although I am wary of anything "global" due to the potential for abuse.

> if so, how do you currently get along without one?

I've found that I have a tendency to overuse generics and--as useful as they are--they aren't the best fit for every task.

Recently I undertook the task of making one of my framework libraries WCF-friendly. By the time I finished, nearly every generic interface had been reworked, or a non-generic equivalent had been created. This was driven by the need to simplify my interfaces to work better as operation contracts and data contracts, but by the time I finished I concluded that the design was cleaner and more intuitive and I had given up very little.

If you evaluate your design you might find that a heavily-constrained generic interface can be replaced by requiring that the input parameter(s) inherit from a base type or an interface.

For example, if type parameter TField1 must be an instantiable class of type Foo, why not just change the interface to require Foo (or more likely, a subclass thereof)?

```
public void Act<TField> where TField : Foo, new() { }
```

becomes

```
public void Act( Foo f ) { }
```

or

```
public void Act( IFoo f ){ }
```

If the class is designed to act upon an input object, usually it must have some knowledge about the object's members and abilities.

For example, `List<T>( T obj )` doesn't really need to do much with the input value other store it, but `TransferMoneyFromAccount<TAccount>( TAccount obj )` probably **does** need to do very specific things with the input data. It could probably be changed to `TransferMoneyFromAccount( IAccount obj )`

For consumers of your libraries, I think an interface enforces the idea of a contract much more elegantly than generics.

> for those who is working on c#: what is a chance that you guys will
>   add this to some new version of c#?

From a guy who does work on c# (Eric Lippert):

> I'm often asked why the compiler does not implement this feature or
>   that feature, and of course the answer is always the same: because no
>   one implemented it. Features start off as unimplemented and only
>   become implemented when people spend effort implementing them: no
>   effort, no feature.

Taken from: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/03/09/why-not-automatically-infer-constraints.aspx (coincidentally, an article relating to generic type constraints)

Comment: I completly agree and I'm all for replacing generics with interfaces.

Comment: well, first off, I found myself getting rid of generics wherever possible for the same reasons as you guys just mentioned, if I can go without them I would, however there are still few situations when it's not possible to do completely and here's where I have to add a generic (there's no way to avoid doing this), and this is when things start going out of control, I can give you very exact situations when it happens if you feel like digging into it, but I doubt you would... so at the end of the day the problems is still there, however we do everything we can to make it less bad

Comment: Hit us with that "exact situation". I bet 100$, that it can correctly be translated into interfaces while keeping all the functionality.

Comment: +1 especially for referring to Eric Lippert as "a guy who does work on c#" :-)

Comment: a quick thought about Eric, it seems like this guy knows everything, and I believe he really does, but for a second, don't you think that somebody can come up with a bright idea which Eric just hasn't had time yet to think about?

Comment: @bonomo - sure, I think many great features come from user feedback. I have seen a lot of discussion around improving generic constraints and I imagine that some of those requests will eventually make it into c#.

Comment: Regarding the code you posted...I don't see anything at first glance looks like it couldn't be treated polymorphically as a base class or interface (e.g. passing a `Noun` object to a method which expects `IPartOfSpeech`). If you need strong types, there is certainly nothing wrong with using generics; perhaps something like Marc's answer describes to minimize how much code must be genericized.

Comment: Since you've taken the time to post detailed code, you might want to open another question specifically asking for feedback on how to reduce/eliminate generics in specific sections (might be an even better question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 4):

I don't like the scenario you present, but another option is nested types:

```
public sealed class Foo<T> where T : Whatever {
    public class Bar { ... }

    public interface IBlap { ... }
}
```

every type inside `Foo<T>` has implicit access to the `T` with no need to duplicate the constraints. For the purpose of code management this can be split over multiple files, again only mentioning the constraint once:

```
// file 1
partial class Foo<T> where T : IWhatever
{

}
// file 2
partial class Foo<T>
{
    public class Bar
    { ... }
}
// file 3
partial  class Foo<T>
{
    public interface IBlap
    { ... }
}
```

But first: sanity check your scenario.

Comment: +0.5 for nesting. Make me think of Newspeak. This way, you can create an instance of your framework that you parametrize with the desired type. Then this instance acts as a factory for all framework elements, and objects know to which instance of the framework they belong to thanks to the implicit outer context. And +0.5 for sanity check first.

Comment: @ewernli note that in c#, a nested type does not have any kind of  implicit parent reference - there is no *instance* required of the outer type (it could even be `static`). IIRC, this is very different to Java.

Comment: Right. (Actually even in java you can nest static classes, and have or not an outer object depending on the situation). But I think it actually great to nest *objects*, as well as *classes*. Your answer made me think of "Modules as Objects in Newspeak" by Gilad Bracha.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very generic (no pun intended) which means that you'll get a generic answer.

I've developed a few frameworks which has extensibility in mind (check my profile). And I've never had to use generics to achieve that. imho generics are used to get type safety for general purpose classes.

Interfaces is what should be used to design frameworks for extensibility.

(Please update your Q if I've missunderstood it)